# Iptables block access to IP for VPN clients

Tags: iptables, vpn, pptp, pptpd

I want to block access to certain websites/IP's for all clients connected to VPN (pptpd or OpenVPN).

This rule:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED  -d IP_address -j REJECT
```

is working only locally.
Server (ping test) can't access blocked IP but clients via VPN can.
How can I block all traffic to specified IP for VPN clients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `OUTPUT` chain only applies to locally generated packets. For packets that are routed via the system, one needs to use the `FORWARD` chain.

So, you need to use this command:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -d IP_address -j REJECT
```